# Setting array values on construction in Java

Tags: java, arrays, char, ascii

Is there a way to set the default values of an array upon construction? I'm initialising a character array like so,

```
char[] chars = new char[value];
```

However, the default value for each element is decimal `0`, rather than decimal `48` which is the ASCII character for `'0'`.

The closest thing I've found is calling:

```
Arrays.fill(chars, '0');
```

which fills the array with the desired decimal value `48`

But this is called after the array has already been created full of `0` values which presumably takes more time?

Comment: A: For what reason you want to do it? B: You can initialize it with as many values you need and a "default" value like this: `char[] c = new char[] { '0' };` but then the size is hard coded

Comment: If it's a small array of known size, you can use the literal notation as well: `char[] chars = {48,48,...}`

Comment: It's part of a method, so I don't want to hard-code the size of the array.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yeah I accidentally surrounded by single quotes. Fixed now.

Comment: Not really, I'm aware of how to declare an array. I wanted to know whether the default value can be adjusted. Turns out it can't.

Answer (score 3):

As per [JLS §15.10.2. Run-Time Evaluation of Array Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.2)

> ...
>
> Then, if a single DimExpr appears, a one-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and each component of the array is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).
>
> ...

and the default value of `char` primitive is `\u0000`.

You could use the array initializer syntax as per [JLS §10.6. Array Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) to avoid the reallocation of array elements:

```
char[] chars = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

but this will only work if you know the array size during compilation.

Comment: Where does it stated that char primitive default value is zero?

Comment: Perhaps I badly worded the answer. The default value of char is null character written as `\u0000` (which is `0x00`, or just `0`) as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

Answer (score 2):

If it is array of primitives it is initialized with the default value for that primitive type. For boolean it is false and for numeric types and char it is 0 (the byte value) or '\u0000' if you need the char.  If you want to set a default value you will have to fill that array manually the way you have found. I don't think you will notice any performance drops.

Comment: Default value for a char is not zero but null. '0' is it's ASCII code.

Comment: nope. Default value for Character is null. But he is using 'char' which is a primitive and not an object and default value is 0

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5). Default value for char is null.

Comment: For char its null "character". Not 0 or null.

Comment: ok my bad in explanation. We are talking about different stuff then. I meant it is 0 as byte value. It is 0 as in the number 0 not the char '0' (because the  '\u0000' actually equals 0). If you create a char a; and do a==0 it will be true

Answer (score 2):

For chars, default value is null character, so you get its ASCII code '0'.

Comment: for Character (and any object actually) default value is null. He has array of char which is a primitive and cannot be null. default value is indeed 0

Comment: Documentation states that "For type char, the default value is the null character, that is, '\u0000'."

Comment: null char which is equal to the number 0 (since chars are actually bytes). Not null - the value. I didn't mean the '0' char - that's what the guy asking wants but he gets the number 0 which is the '\u0000'.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov "*since chars are actually bytes*" - From [JLS §4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1): "*For `char`, from `'\u0000'` to `'\uffff'` inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535*" - So no, `char`s are not `byte`s.

Comment: ok ;) not bytes

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```